# Lua random image

Tags: lua

I have a Lua script I am using in a tabletop game and basically you have a "token" that represents a creature. When it dies, it overlays an image (which I have indicated in an .xml script) with an image of like a blood splat, or tombstone etc.

How do I make it so it would randomize which image gets overlayed?

[The Script is here.](https://pastebin.com/jFrH83Jj)

The lines below (178-184) are the main section that tells it "put image X over the token". I want it to randomize between say, 5 different images..

```
if not widgetDeathIndicator then
    widgetDeathIndicator = tokenCT.addBitmapWidget("token_dead");
    widgetDeathIndicator.setBitmap("token_dead");
    widgetDeathIndicator.setName("deathindicator");
    widgetDeathIndicator.setTooltipText(sName .. " has fallen, as if dead.");
    widgetDeathIndicator.setSize(nWidth-20, nHeight-20);
end
```

`token_dead` is the name of the current image being used, which in the .xml directs to a .png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [math.random](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.random) for this.

```
local images = {
    'token_dead',
    'another_image_name',
    'yet_another_image_name',
}

local image = images[math.random(#images)]
```

`math.random(n)` will return a pseudo-random integer between 1 and n, so if you pass in `#images` (the length of the `images` table) you will get a valid pseudo-random table index for `images`.

To get better randomness you should set [math.randomseed](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.randomseed) before you call math.random. (If you don't set it, then math.random will return the same sequence of "random" numbers each time.)

Comment: I tried this

https://pastebin.com/E0cA2WwG

I couldnt get the code format to work on the comment. Im getting an error

"bitmapwidget: Logical icon (image) does not exist"

Comment: I have an XML file that states the image names and links to each image"

https://pastebin.com/9ZQcBEbQ

Comment: You need to use the variable `image`, not the string `"image"`, in both `tokenCT.addBitmapWidget` and `setBitmap`.

Comment: Got it to work without error, only thing is it isn't randomizing, it's only showing the first image each time. Here's what I have https://pastebin.com/Nd5ZHpSV I added a math.randomseed so the same random sequence doesn't happen but like I said, still not randomizing. almost there haha

Comment: any idea how to make it randomize and not just show the first image?

Comment: Ah, you also need to remove the `if not widgetDeathIndicator then` line, along with the corresponding `end` on line 16. Those mean that the code is only run once, rather than every time you overlay the image. (However, not all of that code needs to be run every time you overlay the image; for the best performance you should move the things that only need to be run once, like generating the table of image names and setting math.randomseed, to somewhere else in your script that isn't run every time.)

Comment: you sir, are a saint. I remove the If/End like you suggested, and moved the image list to the beginning of the code. I added  math.randomseed(os.time()); and then math.random 3 more times after, and it works perfect!

Comment: ah, just noticed something. Once the token reaches 0hp it overlays like I should, but I need to reverse it if it gains HP back.

I noticed the line:
widgetDeathIndicator.setVisible(nPercentHealth>=1);

so I need to reverse that to make it non-visible if Health is over 0